# How to disable Xorg Logging

Tags: linux, centos, xorg, gnome3, x-server

I'm running CentOS 6.X and 7.X machines and use GNOME Desktop extensively, the problem is that Xorg.log.* files are getting big.

I have no need in those logs, I'd like to know how I can disable them or pass -logfile /dev/null -logverbose 0 -verbose 0 to /usr/bin/X

Who and what starts X ? If I can find it I can add the flags I assume

Thank you,
Dennis.

Comment: this doesn`t seem normal, why are the logs so big? Do they present errors?

Comment: No errors, use messages such as these:

[ 15.955] AUDIT: Thu Apr 20 16:22:35 2017: 1384: client 3 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=2835 )
Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 682
[ 15.956] AUDIT: Thu Apr 20 16:22:35 2017: 1384: client 3 disconnected

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have been debugged here [here](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=62431):

> Root Cause:
>   The messages are logged due to `-audit 4` argument passed to Xorg process while gdm launches it.The options is hard-coded in new update of `gdm` package."

(I've seen Gnome doing really stupid things with respect to X, like hardlinked MIT cookies, but this probably tops it).

In the blog post, the solution was to replaced `gdm` with `sddm`. Any other display manager will probably also do, as will either recompiling `gdm` with the `-audit 4` argument patched out, or patching the `gdm` binary with `dd` to overwrite the `-audit 4` argument with spaces or similar.